# Is there a way to display top 10 average ratings of a business type?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following tables in my database scheme

```
CREATE TABLE public.organization_rating
(
    rating integer NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    organization_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT organization_rating_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, organization_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT stars CHECK (rating >= 1 AND rating < 5)
)
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE public.organization
(
    org_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('organization_org_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    phone_number character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bt_id integer NOT NULL,
    bs_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT organization_pkey PRIMARY KEY (org_id),
    CONSTRAINT bs_id FOREIGN KEY (bs_id)
        REFERENCES public.business_step (bs_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT bt_id FOREIGN KEY (bt_id)
        REFERENCES public.business_type (bt_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID
)
```

I would like to implement a query that gives me the following:

1. Top 10 organization ratings per business type
2. Top 10 organizations per business stage
3. Top 3 organizations with worst rating

Since the queries appear to be similar, I just have to order DESC or ASC, depending on the requirement, I just need one query to work and I will have the other 2. I tried implementing this query:

```
CREATE TABLE public.organization
(
    org_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('organization_org_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    phone_number character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bt_id integer NOT NULL,
    bs_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT organization_pkey PRIMARY KEY (org_id),
    CONSTRAINT bs_id FOREIGN KEY (bs_id)
        REFERENCES public.business_step (bs_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT bt_id FOREIGN KEY (bt_id)
        REFERENCES public.business_type (bt_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID
)
```

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT O.org_id, O.bt_id, R.rating
FROM public.organization as O
INNER JOIN public.organization_rating as R ON O.org_id = R.organization_id
WHERE bt_id=1
GROUP by org_id, bt_id, rating
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(rating)) DESC LIMIT 10
```

But the output is as follows:

[image: Output of Query]

There seems to be an error in which various organizations are being duplicated. These are the real average values of the organizations which are being duplicated:

[image]

And

[image]

Why are the organizations id being duplicated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mihai_f87, I was able to construct this query:

```
with average_rating as (
    SELECT organization_id as Organization_ID, ROUND(AVG(rating)) as Rating
    FROM organization_rating
    GROUP BY organization_id
),
ordered_data as (
  select org_id, bt_id, rating, row_number() over (partition by bt_id order by rating desc) rank
  from average_rating r
    join organization o on o.org_id = r.organization_id
    where bt_id = 1
  order by bt_id, rating desc 
)
select  org_id, bt_id, rating
from ordered_data
where rank <= 10
```

With this query, I was able to search top 10 organizations per business type.

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see duplicated records is because the ratings in organization_rating are per user. There can be several users rating an organization. You should first compute an average rating and then join with the organization table.

You can do something like this for bt_id=1:

```
with average_rating as (
    select organization_id as org_id, avg(rating) as avg_rating
    from organization_rating r
    group by org_id
)
select org_id, bt_id, avg_rating
from average_rating r
  join organization o on o.org_id = r.org_id
where r.bt_id = 1
order by avg_rating desc limit 10;
```

If you want to get all data in a single query, you could use a window function:

```
with average_rating as (
    select organization_id as org_id, avg(rating) as avg_rating
    from organization_rating r
    group by org_id
),
ordered_data as (
  select org_id, bt_id, avg_rating, row_number() over (partition by bt_id order by avg_rating desc) rank
  from average_rating r
    join organization o on o.org_id = r.org_id
  order by bt_id, avg_rating desc 
)
select  org_id, bt_id, avg_rating
from ordered_data
where rank <= 10
```

Comment: When I run the query, the following message appears: ERROR:  column reference "org_id" is ambiguous
LINE 7:   select org_id, bt_id, avg_rating, row_number() over (parti...